# What is a projective range?

Tags: projective-geometry

Wikipedia says a projective range is the dual of a pencil of lines on a point. Surely that means: all points on a line.

But Wikipedia also says a projective range may be a projective line or a conic.

This definition and this property seem to be at odds.